# Show or hide a worksheet using a single button

Tags: excel, show-hide, vba

I have a user form with a single button.

Question: Is it possible to show or hide a worksheet using only a single button? If so what the code will look like?

I tried this one so far:

```
Private Sub data_Button_click()

If data_Button.Caption = "Hidden" Then
Worksheets("u").Visible = True
data_Button.Caption = "Visible"
End If

If data_Button.Caption = "Visible" Then
Worksheets("u").Visible = False
data_Button.Caption = "Hidden"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Merge those 2 `If` statements into one like this:

```
Private Sub data_Button_click()

If data_Button.Caption = "Hidden" Then
    Worksheets("u").Visible = True
    data_Button.Caption = "Visible"
ElseIf data_Button.Caption = "Visible" Then
    Worksheets("u").Visible = False
    data_Button.Caption = "Hidden"
End If

End Sub
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
Private Sub data_Button_Click()
    With Worksheets("u")
        .Visible = Not .Visible
        data_Button.Caption = IIf(.Visible, "Hide", "Show")
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: also I tried this one and it worked as well, the coding is much advance and less lines though. can you plainly explain how your code works and why you didnt use if statement. anything else, thank so much!!!

Comment: `Not` operator sets the opposite state of the `.Visible` property: if the sheet is visible then it makes it hidden, and vice versa. `IIf` actually is a shortened form of `If .. Then .. Else .. End If` statement, and used to change the button caption corresponding the current state.